# Pandas row-wise aggregation with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe where there's three levels of row indexing. The last level is a datetime index. There are nan values and I am trying to fill them with the average of each row at the datetime level. How can I go about doing this?

```
data_df

Level 0 | Level 1 |        Level 2      |      
A           123     2019-01-28 17:00:00 |   3  |  1    | nan
                    2019-01-28 18:00:00 |   2  |  nan  | 1
                    2019-01-28 19:00:00 |  nan |  nan  | 5
            234     2019-01-28 05:00:00 |   1  |  1    | 3
                    2019-01-28 06:00:00 |   nan  |  nan  | nan
```

Some rows may all be nan values. In this case I want to fill the row with 0's. Some rows may have all values filled in so imputing with average isn't needed.

I want this the following result:

```
Level 0 | Level 1 |        Level 2      |      
A           123     2019-01-28 17:00:00 |   3  |  1    | 2
                    2019-01-28 18:00:00 |   2  |  1.5  | 1
                    2019-01-28 19:00:00 |  5   |  5    | 5
            234     2019-01-28 05:00:00 |   1  |  1    | 3
                    2019-01-28 06:00:00 |   0  |  0  | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with `mean` per rows and last convert only `NaN`s rows by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.isna(), df.mean(axis=1), axis=0).fillna(0)
print (df)
                                       a    b    c
Level 0 Level 1 Level 2                           
A       123     2019-01-28 17:00:00  3.0  1.0  2.0
                2019-01-28 18:00:00  2.0  1.5  1.0
                2019-01-28 19:00:00  5.0  5.0  5.0
        234     2019-01-28 05:00:00  1.0  1.0  3.0
                2019-01-28 06:00:00  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for replace, but because not implemented `df.fillna(df.mean(axis=1), axis=1)` is necessary double transpose:

```
df = df.T.fillna(df.mean(axis=1)).fillna(0).T
```